# CSS full-height two-column layout with navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout with two columns, a sidebar and main content, that need to stretch the **height** of the browser. So, `100%`, less the height of my Twitter Bootstrap `navbar` which is initially `40px` in height. That `40px` changes via Twitter Bootstrap CSS if you're viewing the page in a narrow browser (like on a mobile device). The new height is based on the number of links in the `navbar`, so it's dynamic.

I know I can come up with some JavaScript to adjust the `top` property to "shrink" my columns' height. But I'd really like to do it in CSS if I can.

Note that I can't just overlap the columns by changing the `z-index`.

See the model in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/mu4Ey/3/

**Layout**

```
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
| navbar                                  |
+ - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|       |                                 |
|< 20% >|<-- 80% ------------------------>|
|       |                                 |
|       | Google Maps API map contained   |
|       | here.                           |
|       |                                 |
|       |                                 |
|       |                                 |
|       |                                 |
+ - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar, .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    left: 0;
    right: 80%;
}

.content {
    left: 20%;
    right: 0;
}​
```

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

See an example of the Twitter Bootstrap `navbar` here: http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/MDZaG/

Increase the size of the browser or the "result" frame to see the non-collapsed `navbar`.

Another example and documentation: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

**EDIT 2**

The contents of the two columns will not affect the columns' height; they will always be `100%` minus the height of the `navbar`:

[image: example]

**EDIT 3**

I changed the CSS above and the jsfiddle link so that the positioning is `absolute` to discourage confusion.

**FINAL EDIT: CHOSEN SOLUTION**

Since there seems to be no CSS solution beyond CSS3 `calc`, I wrote some js to do the trick...

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/mu4Ey/5/

I searched through the Twitter Bootstrap js source code and figured out that they were calculating the new height from the `navbar`'s `scrollHeight`. My js does the same and animates the CSS `top` property with a slight lag to hide the body. It's a horrible solution because Twitter Bootstrap could alter the animation speed and break my js.

What I *should* do is fin out how to target browsers that support CSS3 `calc` and let them use it and have all other browsers use the js.

Comment: with pure css you cannot calculate something like 100%-40px. You need to use javascript for it.

Comment: Actually you can using css3's calc. It is starting to get supported but I wouldn't consider it safe yet.

Comment: @SvenBieder The "100%-40px" CSS is already written and works: http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/mu4Ey/ I'm trying to see if there is way to change that working CSS to something that works with "relative" values/positions instead of absolute pixels. That way when the 40px changes, the column height will adjust itself.

Comment: @flackend is position:fixed on the columns what you really need?

Comment: that is exactly what I was talking about. You can give static values for margin or top,left... but the only way you can work dynamically with css is when you go with fluid layouts (%-based), but that will not work out for your purpose. Is there a special reason that speaks against two lines of javascript to solve the problem?

Comment: @SvenBieder When the `navbar` expands it uses an animation so I'd need to find a plugin or something that listens for a div's height to match the animation or wait for the animation to finish to update the CSS. @JOPLOmacedo I could use `absolute` to accomplish the same thing. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I can't really imagine what kind of menu you have that needs to enlarge the complete header instead of making it's animation to open and close layered over the content. Do you have an example link for that?

Comment: @flackend I don't know what kind of layout you want so I'm not really sure. Help me out then. Is the height of the content and sidebar columns always 100%(minus whatever) or will it expand if their inner contents overflow the height of the browser's window?

Comment: What do you mean you can't just overlap the columns ? Can't or won't ? Have you tried applying that : `.navbar { position: relative;z-index: XXX; }`

Comment: @Sherbrow I "can't" because it would cover up the contents of my columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Not without using css3 features which do not have the proper browser support yet ('flexbox', for example, might be able to achieve this - I'm not really sure as I haven't yet played enough with it. Again, I'm waiting for a better support).

That being said, what I would suggest would be to use media queries. Figure out where the layout breaks and add one around that point where you'd increase the height and adjust the top value for the content and sidebar divs. A better solution, imo, still using media queries, would be to put your nav inside a select element (or your own made dropdown) when you get below a certain width. That way you could keep the 'top' and 'height' unchanged.

Comment: Hadn't read your latest edit.  This solution answers a different need. Let me try again.

Answer (score 1):

If they will always be 100% height, then create 3 absolutely positioned divs, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ywySt/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is actually what I have already, but remixed a little.